# Crash while cleaning DirectX application

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I have a DirectX application. It's very simple but I have a problem with it. I create device, device context etc. and everything is working but when I quit, a crash occurs and the error is: `HEAP: Free Heap block 3ad7d18 modified at 3ad7d98 after it was freed`. It occurs only if I call `IDXGISwapChain Present` function at least once. If I don't, then the whole cleaning process goes well. Moreover I call `Release` on every COM object and the crash ALWAYS occurs only when I release the last COM object (order doesn't matter). I use DirectX 11 (Win8 SDK) on Windows 7, MS Visual 2012.

My message loop function:

```
int Engine::run( ){

    MSG msg = { 0 };
    mTimeCounter->restart( ); // doesn't matter
    while( msg.message != WM_QUIT ){ 
        if( PeekMessage( &msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) ){
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        } else {
            updateScene( mTimeCounter->deltaTime( ) );
            drawScene( );  
        }  
    }

    return static_cast<int>( msg.wParam );
}
```

updateScene do nothing now and draw scene only call this two functions:

```
void Engine::sceneBegin( ){
    static FLOAT color[] = { 0.05f, 0.15f, 0.05f, 1.0f }; 
    mDeviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView( mBackBufferView, color );
    mDeviceContext->ClearDepthStencilView( mDepthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1, 0 );
}


void Engine::sceneEnd( ){
    mSwapChain->Present( 0, 0 ); // crash do not occure if i comment this line of code
}
```

Part of messages switch:

```
   case WM_QUIT : // i do not receive it even once because i press window's X button and it destroy window before i could receive WM_QUIT ( or not? :P )
    {

                DestroyWindow( mMainWnd );
            }
            break;

            case WM_DESTROY : // i receive it if press window's X button
            {
                PostQuitMessage( 0 ); 
            }  
            break;
return DefWindowProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
```

Main function in which i initialize and start my engine:

```
EngTest *eng = new EngTest( );
eng->initialize( hInstance, L"Hi", show );
int r = eng->run( );
delete eng; // crash occures here but only if i call Present at least once.
```

Shutdown:

```
// called in Engine's destructor
void Engine::shutdown( ){ 
    RELEASE_COM( mDepthStencilView );
    RELEASE_COM( mDepthStencilBuffer );
    RELEASE_COM( mBackBufferView );
    RELEASE_COM( mSwapChain );
    if( mDeviceContext )
        mDeviceContext->ClearState( );
    RELEASE_COM( mDeviceContext );
    RELEASE_COM( mDevice );  
}
```

RELEASE_COM

```
#define RELEASE_COM( x ) { if( x != NULL ) { x->Release( ); x = NULL; } }
```

Comment: One quick comment on your window procedure code: WM_QUIT will never make it to the window procedure as it is meant as a signal to the message pump (your PeekMessage call) that the program's windows have all been closed down, and that the program should also close. Your check for WM_QUIT should go after the call to PeekMessage, but before the call to Translate/DispatchMessage. You may want WM_CLOSE, which is fired whenever the user requests to close the window (i.e. hits the X button or presses ALT+F4 or selects Close from the Window menu). 

Also your code style reminds me of Frank Luna's...

Comment: I think you are correct with WM_QUIT message, thanks :) Now it's quite old code. I started to use smart pointers and com smart pointers. And i have a Frank Luna's book. This for DirectX 11 and i like it :)

Answer (score 3):

Ok... That is really annoying. This code seems to be good and problem was in drivers or sth. When i installed new drivers and reboot PC twice then problem disappeared.

Comment: which driver you were using?

Comment: i'm not sure. First of all, i have GeForce 540M. Now i'm using driver v. 320.18 with NVIDIA GeForce Experience software which I didn't have before update... I can only estimate time which passed since my last drivers update. Maybe it was 3 months but I'm not sure, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

**For what is worth it, this is how I fixed the exactly same issue.** Occurred with just `Clear()` in render code and only when `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` was on *(to add to the mystery)*:

```
case WM_CLOSE: // X clicked or Alt+F4
    ::DestroyWindow(hWnd); // triggers WM_DESTROY
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    gD3d11Context->ClearState();
    PostQuitMessage(0); // this triggers the WM_QUIT to break the loop
    break;
```

Plus I have my pointers wrapped in a custom `ComPtr` implementation. They are members of the class and self-destruct in reverse order of construction. So no `->Release()` stacks :)